# C# Refresh of the event in debug mode

Tags: c#, debugging, events

Here I try to recover some values into variables.

I send a message to a server which returns different values. These values are read in a thread. I catch all values returned by the server with an event.

I try to store it but I have a problem: when I use my debugger I can see all refresh of my event only at the end (at display time in a WindowsForm).

Example with code:

```
ModuleProtocole.SendMessage("VER"); // after this command I will receive the version
ModuleProtocole.SendMessage("NA1"); // after this command I will receive the name of hardware

public void MessageRec(object source, MesACK e)
{
 ReceptionMessage = e.getinfos(); //My globale variable ReceptionMessage is refresh for every new value on port
}

if(ReceptionMessage[0] == "M") //When i debug line by line ReceptionMessage is always = "Monitor" but at the end of debug all variable like "Name" is completed by the good word
   Version = ReceptionMessage;
else Name=ReceptionMessage;
```

So my question is: Why my event is refresh only one time in debug? In my code, it should be trigger 2 times but only the first one is show and apply to variables in debug console.

Comment: Can you add the declaration, the subscription and invoke of event?

Comment: You need an [MCVE]

Comment: @Vernou , yes I can but I don't know if a speciale rule in C# say an event is trigger only one time in debug mode or something like that?

Comment: @MichaelRandall when example is more than 10 lines, people don't take time for the post, no problem if no one can answer with this, i will work more and better for find an other solution

Comment: Its hard to know what you are doing, what you are trying to do, and what you are seeing.... Yes i understand language may be a problem, that is why we ask for a [MCVE], if we could copy and paste this into Visual Studio and see what you are seeing, we have a better chance to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I colleague found the solution: in the subscribe function to the event, add Console.Writeline(ReceptionMessage); then you can see refresh of ReceptionMessage.
Event is complicated in debug mode, this is the best way for see the refresh !

```
public void MessageRec(object source, MesACK e)
{
 ReceptionMessage = e.getinfos();
 Console.Writline(ReceptionMessage);
}
```